# How to zip single file using archive module

Tags: node.js, archiverjs

Im trying to zip a single file using [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and I succeed but resulting zip file contains directory when unzipped and I want just the file.

Here is a sample code:

```
export async function zipFile(srcFilePath: string, zipFilePath: string) {
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipFilePath);
  const archive = archiver('zip',{
    zlib:{
      level: 9
    }
  })

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    output.on('close', function() {
      console.log('ARCHIVE FINISHED.');
      resolve(zipFilePath)
    });

    archive.on('error', function(err) {
      reject(err)
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    archive.file(srcFilePath, {name:path.basename(srcFilePath)})

    archive.finalize();

  })
}

  const zippedFile = await zipFile(
    "/home/rikotech/code/scalewest/repos/hype-nielsen-report/csv/csv.csv",
    "/home/rikotech/code/scalewest/repos/hype-nielsen-report/csv/zipped.zip"
  );
```

The result is `zipped.zip` and when I unzip it I see a folder named `zipped` and then iside the folder I have the unzipped file `csv.csv`.

I want when I unzip the zip file to get a file (the csv file) not a folder and in it the file.
[image]

Comment: the code looks fine. how are you unzipping it, because the unzipping tool might be creating that folder..

Comment: @traynor
right click on the zip file -> extract here (Ubuntu 20)

Comment: can you try with unzip via CLI, or some tool